# min-height Not Working in Google Chrome

Tags: css

Hello i seem to have a problem with what could be technically called 'a huge gap down the bottom of my website on Google Chrome'. I think it is to do with this code-

```
#container {
    width: 968px;
    min-height: 2100px;
}
```

I have changed the min height down to 600px and things seem to be ok on Firefox and IE9. On Chrome though there is a massive gap. You can view my site here-
http://onlinebanter.com/

It's depressing as i use Chrome for the admin side of things on my site and i have to look at all day every day and it's starting to get me a little down. I have asked about the internet but have had no response even from the place where i bought the theme (they seem to have the same problem on their demo site)

Id there anyway to fox this?

Thanks

Reg.

Comment: This site is a disaster in all my browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the actual problem...

You're using an `HTML 4 Transitional` `doctype` with namespaces in your `<html>`. Funny and faulty.

-- edit 1

The problem is the weird located footer img. Make that a block with CSS and you're golden:  `display: block;`

-- edit 2

The min-height has nothing to do with it. Why do you even have a min-height??

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Rudie. Forgive my lack of knowledge here whilst i attempt you fixes. The code that brings that footer image is-<img src="<?php print base_path().drupal_get_path('theme', 'drupalmagazine'); ?>/images/footer.gif"> If i just remove that code from my page things seem fine. I will go and work out how to make it inline. IT shouldnt be that hard and i need to learn. Im feeling better already just seeing it not there. I will also look into that namespaces in my html. Thanks

Comment: <div style="display:block;"><img src="<?php print base_path().drupal_get_path('theme', 'drupalmagazine'); ?>/images/footer.gif"></div> sorted me out. Thanks very much Rudie :)

Comment: Reg, if this was your best answer, please let Stackoverflow know by clicking the tick image next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rudie i will do. Sorry. Rudie or anyone whilst i am here. I asked the theme maker about the 'funny and faulty' namespaces you mentioned. He said that it must be a module doing this. Here is the demo theme from the makers. is it the same on their demo? thannks [link](http://www.themesnap.com/theme-demos/magazine-plus)